# How to parse JSON documents not represented as collection in Java

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I' m trying to write Jersey client to parse this Json and retrieve the name (for ex: emp), title and href.

```
{
  "Resources" : {
    "Emp" : {
      "title" : "Employee",
      "links" : [ {
        "rel" : "self",
        "href" : "https://localhost:8080/resources/emp/describe",
        "name" : "self",
        "kind" : "describe"
      } ]
    },
    "Dept" : {
      "title" : "Department",
      "links" : [ {
        "rel" : "self",
        "href" : "https://localhost:8080/resources/dept/describe",
        "name" : "self",
        "kind" : "describe"
      } ]
    },
    "Pay" : {
      "title" : "Payroll",
      "links" : [ {
        "rel" : "self",
        "href" : "https://localhost:8080/resources/pay/describe",
        "name" : "self",
        "kind" : "describe"
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

and the java class looks like this -

```
public class Resource {
    private String name;
    private String title;
    private String describeUrl;
}
```

Ideally I would have thought the list of resources (Emp, Dept, Pay) would have represented as a collection [] in which case I could have assigned this to JSONArray (org.json).

I verified that the JSON document is valid and in accepted format via linter (https://jsonlint.com/)

In this case, how are we expected to parse the JSON. Any help pls ?

Comment: I think you'll need a `JsonAdapter`, here's a site which gives quite an indepth intoduction:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-json-moshi

Comment: Do you look for [Entity Data Filtering](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/entity-filtering.html)?